# How can I find world writable files and folders and set the sticky bit?

Tags: command-line, permissions, find

I want to do the following:

1. Need to find all world writable files and folders from `/` root.
2. If found, I need to check whether the sticky bit is set or not.
3. If the sticky bit is not set, then set it.

Can we come up with a command line solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this using `find`'s `-perm -mode` format. From `man find`:

> -perm -mode
>
> All  of  the  permission bits mode are set for the file.  Symbolic
>   modes are accepted in this form,
>         and this is usually the way in which would want to use them.  You must specify `u',`g' or  `o'  if
>         you use a symbolic mode.   See the EXAMPLES section for some illustrative examples.

So, to find all files that are world writeable, irrespective of what other permissions they have, you can do:

```
find / -perm -o+w
```

To set the sticky bit, use `-exec`:

```
find . -perm -o+w -exec chmod +t {} +
```

Comment: NB: use `find / -not -type l -perm -o+w` if you don't want output to include the names of symbolic links as well.

Answer (score 3):

This command should find writable directories all in one command, I find myself using this quite often. This it the optimal command! ;) hope it serves you well:

```
find / -type d \( -perm -g+w -or -perm -o+w \) -exec ls -adl {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

This command might work for you:

```
find / -type f! -path "/ proc / *" -prune -perm o + w exec ls {} -lg /; 2&gt; / dev / null
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is this one:

Find world writable folders on local disks, with sticky bit not set and set it:

```
df --local -P 2> /dev/null | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | \
xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type d \( -perm -0002 -a -perm -1000 \) exec chmod +t {} \;
```